# How to save text file command line using os.system?

Tags: python, mac

I have a Azure VM, and my personal computer is MAC OS

## Predict.py

```
import os
os.chdir("PATH")
os.chdir("tensor")
os.system(". bin/activate")
os.system("tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image --input_layer=Mul --output_layer=final_result --labels=PATH --image=PATH --graph=PATH")
```

## at MAC (Personal Com.)

```
python3 Predict.py make &> PATH
```

## result

Not Commandline just write text file

## but, Ubuntu(= Azure VM)

```
python3 Predict.py make &> PATH
```

## result

python3 result in command line

I want to get same result. What should I do?
plz Help me.

Comment: This doesn't look like anything I know from linux/unix. Are you sure you are using a linux shell?

Comment: I Used MAC Terminal (Personal Com.) and Linux Shell(Azure VM).

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking, but my *guess* is the MAC terminal is using `bash` where `&> file` is a synonym for `> file 2>&1` (i.e. redirected both stdout and stderr to file) whereas you have set your shell to `sh` (or `dash`) on Ubuntu where `&> file` will result in backgrounding the process and writing nothing to `file`

Comment: Sorry, never heard about azure VM, and when I duck for it I get keywords "microsoft" and "pricing". To get ahead with your question, when you type _echo $0_ , what do you get? If you are using _any common kind of linux shell_ you should get some answer like _bash_, or _ksh_.

Comment: As to @steeldriver s comment: you can always try _echo HelloWorld > myfile.txt_ and if this result in a file named myfile.txt with content HelloWorld, your problem is solved.

Comment: because of comment, I can solve now.
Especially thanks to steeldriver was able to tidy up. 
Thanks to everyone who answered. Thank you.

Comment: Your Predict.py file should be better written as a shell script. These four Python lines hurt my eyes.